# Modifying IPA to bypass custom SSL pinning

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, reverse-engineering

I'm a security researcher currently helping a group of developers make a banking app more secure. We are now trying to implement an SSL-Pinning mechanism that would defer people from trying to analyze the traffic of the application by using a web proxy.

Normal library-based mechanisms can be bypassed by the use of SSL killswitch or similar utilities which patch the system library thus tricking any application into thinking that an SSL certificate is valid, even when it is self-signed.

So I suggested that a custom SSL-Pinning mechanisms, which compare a certificate with hardcoded values, such as public key, signature and valid periods was implemented.

Now I'm trying to bypass it but I found a problem which I have to solve before starting. Is there a way to modify the IPA file (which is essentially a zip file with a signature), and then put it all back together and run it on a jailbroken device running IOS 8?

I want to clarify that this is a black-box approach, which means that I can't just ask the developers to resign it or to avoid that mechanism, because a real attacker wouldn't have that resource.

Thanks for the help.
Alex.

Comment: Are you asking for help in cracking the IPA of a banking app?  That's what it looks like to me.  Maybe the question is legitimate but maybe it's not, I can't tell from looking at your profile.

Comment: Yes I'm asking for help in cracking the IPA of a banking app, it's part of my job. I'm a security researcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I've never reverse-engineered any iOS app myself.

IPAs from iTunes are protected by a DRM called FairPlay. You need to first decrypt an IPA before reverse-engineering it.
You can use otool to find out if an IPA is encrypted or not.
Please read the reply from jg0 for a step-by-step guide here: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source

After the decryption, I suggest to use Hopper instead of IDA, it is much cheaper and it comes with a decompiler (pseudo-code).

Comment: What I'm actually asking is how to repack it in order to be able to execute it on an IOS 8 device.

Comment: You need to analyze the code with IDA, and then patch it using an hex editor (sorry, AFAIK, there is no stuff like ollydbg that can help you to patch the code on the fly :( but I'm sure about Hopper). Then you can transfer the hacked executable back to your device, replacing the original one. By the way, there are a lot of tutorials about this.

Comment: But the problem is that if I modify the IPA, the signature will become invalid and IOS won't accept it. is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: As I've said, I'm not an iOS expert, but AFAIK you can use many tools (from cydia) to install unsigned ipas. A simple google search suggest this link: http://www.jailbreakqa.com/questions/321004/installing-unsigned-app-on-jailbroken-idevice